# Remove grey border around pavucontrol in 16.04

Tags: gtk3, 16.04, awesome, pavucontrol

This issue is best illustrated with an image:

[image: Screen shot of pavucontrol with the grey borders around the application content]

As you can see above there is a grey border around the actual contents of the application.

What I've tried thus far is to modify the contents of .config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css according to the pointers given on a probably unrelated bug on [CSD](https://github.com/shimmerproject/Numix/issues/206).

I've tried to select the area around the contents with gtk-inspector but to no avail.

[image: Trying to target the grey area with gtk-inspector.]

Neither does applying, as seen above, a style removing margins, padding and borders to the background-class associated with the upper-most gtk element have any effect.

Having no experience at all with gtk development I'm unsure where to go from here.

Comment: Questions about bugs and about future releases are off-topic here, because they should be posted as bug report on Launchpad against the respective package, so that the developers can quickly fix it.

Comment: Well, it's not necessarily a bug as much as it is a question of taste and themes. Perhaps my wording was off. But then are all questions about 16.04 off topic until its release?

Comment: I ended up filing a bug report on launchpad either way: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pavucontrol/+bug/1564349

Comment: Ford_Prefect in #pulseaudio@irc.freenode.net has submitted a patch for this  bug: https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/pulseaudio-discuss/2016-March/025937.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that this was a bug in pavucontrol which should be fixed with a future release: https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/pulseaudio-discuss/2016-March/025937.html

Comment: Nice that you found a solution. Don't forget to accept your own answer after the delay (2 days from asking the question) is over.

Comment: Cheers @ByteCommander!